# Sending UDP as bytes with VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I've been trying to get vbscript to send UDP, but I'm totally stuck on how to do so. My options are limited since it's being used in Chyron's LyricPRO graphics software.

I've tried using the createobject method to try some of the things I've found, e.g. Winsock, but so far I have had no luck.

```
set wObj = CreateObject("mswinsock.winsock")
```

So far anything I try pops up an error message saying that the ActiveX component can't create the object.

Comment: "Since the Winsock control is a "licensed control" one must pass a runtime license to the script host.

This works fine for an HTA or even an HTML page, because there is a special IE mechanism for doing it.

WSH has no such facility however.  This means that such a script, whether WScript or CScript, will only run on machines that have a developer license installed, usually by installing Visual Studio or VB."

Comment: @ArnovanBoven nice direct quote from [VBScript and Winsock thread on Tek-Tips.com](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=938038).

Comment: There are plenty of examples of COM DLL wrappers that provide socket functionality for TCP/UDP client/server communication. Quick google search brought up a free COM DLL for UDP called [SimpleSocket](http://spotwise.com/2006/06/08/simplesocket/), give it a go.

Comment: @Lankymart I'll have to look into that, but I think options would be limited as this would have to be installed on multiple on-air devices and I'm not sure if it'd run afoul of IT policies. But thank you.